# How to import contacts from Gmail, Yahoo, Aol, Hotmail, msn, etc

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to import contact list in my Ruby On Rails application.
  I got succeed using sailthru API, but the problem is, it replies empty result for aol, msn, hotmail.
  I also tried rails gem 'contacts', that is also not replying for all(only answers for gmail, yahoo, aol). :(

Thanks to reply in advance,
Alpesh Modi

Comment: Please provide more details. What exactly happens? Log info?

Comment: Hey Shripad,
  Problem is I want to fetch contact list of gmail, yahoo, Aol, etc.. in Ruby on Rails application.<br/>
  Not getting success.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that a lot of the imports will break because of changes on the remote end. Your best may be to purchase a third party solution who will keep up with that. I *would* suggest Octazen (we use them) but they aren't accepting new customers as they were recently bought out by Facebook.